# How do you find the types of items in a list that contains a dictionary, integer, float and string?

Tags: python

I have to identify the type of items contained in a list but it gives an incomplete output.

It looks something like this

```
datalist = [
    {"semester": 1, "year": "2020"},
    1452,
    11.23,
    1 + 2j,
    True,
    "Programming2A",
    (0, -1),
    [5, 12],
]

for item in datalist:
    print("Type of ", item, " is ", type(item))
```

Comment: Why are you saying that it is giving incomplete output? What is the output you get and what is your expected output?

Comment: Do you want the type of the nested values ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get all of the types, including inner ones. Here is a simple procedural way you can do that. It simply determines if an inner type is a container type, and if it is it sends it back through the function.

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict

def type_printer(target):
    if isinstance(target, (List, Tuple, Dict)):
        for t in target:
            print(f'Type of {t}  is: {type(t)}')
            if isinstance(t, (List, Tuple, Dict)):
                type_printer(t)
                
datalist = [{"semester":1, "year":'2020'}, 1452, 11.23, 1+2j, True, "Programming2A", (0, -1), [5, 12]]

type_printer(datalist)
```

As stated in a below comment, the `typing library` is for type annotations. I don't see why it matters considering it works identical, but here is another version that uses the types directly. I also disagree with the comment. I opine that the annotated type makes it clearer that I am looking for that type. Whereas the built-in looks like an instance. Even the syntax highlighting for this site seems to agree.

```
def type_printer(target):
    if isinstance(target, (list, tuple, dict)):
        for t in target:
            print(f'Type of {t}  is: {type(t)}')
            if isinstance(t, (list, tuple, dict)):
                type_printer(t)
                
datalist = [{"semester":1, "year":'2020'}, 1452, 11.23, 1+2j, True, "Programming2A", (0, -1), [5, 12]]

type_printer(datalist)
```

Comment: why on earth are you using `from typing import List, Tuple, Dict`? Those are for type-annotations, use `(list, tuple, dict)`

Comment: Because they are for type-annotations. I'm surprised it even works, it is at the very least unidiomatic. Use the built-ins